# How to translate relative closure into convergence of sequences?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

There is a usual property/definition of closed set: for any convergent sequence of elements in the set, its limit belongs to the closed set itself.

Let's have $Y\subset X$, where $Y$ is a subspace of $X$.

The relative closure of $A$ with respect to $Y$ is
$$\text{cl}_Y(A)=\text{cl}_X(A)\cap Y.$$

How do we translate this into a property of convergent sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is relatively closed (= closed in the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)) iff for every [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) (sequences don't suffice in general, but only for first-countable spaces) in $A$ which is convergent in $X$ to a limit in $Y$ this limit is actually in $A$.

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for your answer. ;)

Comment: You're welcome!